# Multiple active "pages" using Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, aurelia

Using Aurelia, is there any way to have multiple dynamicly loaded "pages" (components, maybe) active at a time? Much like Azure's dashboard has a left-to-right flow of functionality. See this fiddle to illustrate what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/eqr53dc0/2/

**Update**

I can accomplish this with `<compose repeat.for="panel of panels" view-model.bind="panel"></compose>` and load up `panels` on my view-model with the panels which need to be shown. Let me know if this is bad form!

[image: Example]

Each "panel" would be active/usable at any given time. I'm just not sure how to structure this using Aurelia.

**HTML**

```
<header>header</header>
<div id="content">
  <div class="panel">
    <p>This is a panel, or a "page". Some action within this panel will spawn the panel to the right.</p>
    <button>continue</button>
  </div>
  <div class="panel hidden">
    <p>This is a panel, or a "page". Some action within this panel will spawn the panel to the right.</p>
    <button>continue</button>
  </div>
  <div class="panel hidden">
    <p>This is a panel, or a "page". Some action within this panel will spawn the panel to the right.</p>
    <button>continue</button>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  color: #fff;
}

header,
footer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #333;
}

#content {
  background-color: #666;
}

.panel {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #501136;
}

.panel.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $parent = $this.parent();

    $parent.next().removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: Are the pages left to right dependent of one another? If so, this is a child router strategy.

Comment: Probably/maybe. I'd like to hear more...but I'm sorry that it's not that well defined. In a lot of cases, data entered in panel1 may be required by and used by panel 2+.

Comment: I agree with @MatthewJamesDavis. Child Router is your choice

Comment: ill write up a detailed answer tomorrow

Comment: @JoshM. is there an answer to this, that could be marked and close the question?

Comment: @Aligned -- not sure, I didn't end up going with this UI/UX, IIRC.